# Dataframe column data is getting replaced with some other column data after doing filtering

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns "sender","recipient","subject", "body". I need to filter the data with an emailid which is in sender or recipient column

```
df_new=df.loc[(df['sender'] == searchEmail) | (df['recipient'] == searchEmail)]
```

Filtering is working perfectly, but after filtering
print(df_new) shows "subject" and "body" columns are filled with some other data. What is the issue here?

Comment: See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and make changes to your Q.

Comment: @DeepSpace .loc is not making any difference to my issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df[df['subject'].str.contains("hello")]


df[df['body'].str.contains("hello")]
```